# Bootstrap modal content not filling up modal-body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Apologies for a possible redundant question, but searching for keywords like "fill" didn't really help with the problem at hand.

I'm having trouble getting the contents of a Bootstrap Modal body to fill the entirety of the body's space.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#benchmarkModal" id="benchmark">Select Benchmark</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="benchmarkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="benchmarkModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="benchmarkModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="select-menu">
                  <select multiple class="form-control">
                    <option value="test_1" selected"=selected">test_1</option>
                    <option value="test_2" selected"=selected">test_2</option>
                    <option value="test_3" selected"=selected">test_3</option>
                    <option value="test_4" selected"=selected">test_4</option>
                    <option value="test_5" selected"=selected">test_5</option>
                    <option value="test_6" selected"=selected">test_6</option>
                    <option value="test_7" selected"=selected">test_7</option>
                    <option value="test_8" selected"=selected">test_8</option>
                    <option value="test_9" selected"=selected">test_9</option>
                    <option value="test_10" selected"=selected">test_10</option>
                    <option value="test_11" selected"=selected">test_11</option>
                    <option value="test_12" selected"=selected">test_12</option>
                    <option value="test_13" selected"=selected">test_13</option>
                    <option value="test_14" selected"=selected">test_14</option>
                    <option value="test_15" selected"=selected">test_15</option>
                    <option value="test_16" selected"=selected">test_16</option>
                    <option value="test_17" selected"=selected">test_17</option>
                    <option value="test_18" selected"=selected">test_18</option>
                    <option value="test_19" selected"=selected">test_19</option>
                    <option value="test_20" selected"=selected">test_20</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

and this is the css file:

```
.modal-dialog,
.modal-content {
    /* 80% of window height */
    height: 80vh;
}
```

All I'm trying to do is to get the select multiple menu to fill the entire modal-body and I have no idea how to do it.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xupfmkL/ (stretch the result box to get a better view of what's going on)

Comment: I have a feeling that your custom CSS might not be working. Can you check and confirm if you have linked your custom css properly?

Comment: Yes, I've linked it properly because without the 80vh property the modal is shrunk down to the size of the select multiple section. By including the css the modal itself expands but the select multiple section does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.modal-dialog {
    height: 80vh;
}
.modal-content{
  height:100%;
}

.select-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.select-menu .form-control{
  height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2xupfmkL/9/